# Removing text to display from multiple cells in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, hyperlink

What I want is to remove "Text to display" like in column E, and extract plain link from it for the column F. Need formula for multiple cells.
Scripts are not an option as they're disabled in our organization.

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InEDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the links are generated with the hyperlink function you can enter the following in F1 and drag down:

```
=RegexExtract(FormulaText(E1),"""(.*?)""")
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are not :(